# Forcing certain rows to end of results but maintaining sort order

Tags: sql

A variation of this question has been asked before with people suggesting to do a `order by case when ...` to specify a certain value as either 0 or 1 so that it is forced to the end. However, for my needs the values should be at the end of the results AND must be ordered in the same way as the results above them.

This is how I am being requested to pull my data:

**1st half**: Contains all rows except when`column1='xyz'`, `order by column2, column3, column1`

**2nd half**: Contains only rows where `column1='xyz'`, `order by column2, column3, column1`

All of these values are in a single set of results. Is there a way to do this entirely in the SQL? Or do I need to create two separate queries and just add the two together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you use `case` with additional columns for sorting:

```
order by (case when column1 = 'xyz' then 1 else 0 end),
         column2, column3, column1
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how the first element in the order by is not overridden by the following elements. I tried this and it worked, but I don't get how the ordering is maintained. Could you explain please?

Comment: @mighty_squash . . . The first expression returns 0 or 1 depending on the value of `column1`.  That is what gets sorted first.  The first expression has precedence.